# Is there a AutoIt keypress example?

Tags: autoit

I am reading AutoIt Your Quick Guide but still not sure how to actually implemented it.

My setting, a opened notpad waiting for input.

What I want to do is to have a while loop and continue press a keystroke (e.g. keycode 20, #3 key, or multiple keystrokes) in a random period to that opened notepad.

How do I do it? I know send a keypress is using function Send ( "keys" [, flag = 0] ) But there is no number key reference in the book, and how do I tell the autoit to send keystroke to the specific program (notepad, in my example)

How I connect these all together?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you absolve the [Notepad Tutorial](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/notepad/notepad.htm) from the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`ControlSend()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) in the help file, there is a Notepad example for you to decipher. [`Send()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) is a little unpredictable when you wish to send keystrokes to a particular window, as AutoIt simulates the keystrokes and thus if another window takes focus during the loop, then this will receive the keys.